# .NET MAUI Android Emulator Cannot Execute dll Visual Studio Mac

Tags: maui, visual-studio-mac, .net-8.0

I am running Visual Studio on a Mac for .NET MAUI.  I was playing around with some package versions following a Visual Studio update about a week ago, and now when I try to run my project on the Android Emulator, I get a message that says `Cannot execute "[my directory path]/bin/Debug/net7.0-android/[my project name].dll`.  The project still runs on the iOS Simulator without issue.

[image: Visual Studio Error Message]

When I open Project Properties, I see the Android Target is now missing.  It was previously shown on this screen.

[image: Project Properties]

I *think* this started when I tried to change the `Target .NET Runtime` to .NET 8.0 for Android before I had .NET 8.0 installed.  The `Deploying to Device` output appears to be normal, although I admit I don't usually pay much attention to it and probably wouldn't recognize an anomaly.

[image: Deploying to Device output]

I have attempted the following and none seemed to solve the problem:

1. Restart Visual Studio
2. Restart Android Emulator
3. Restart Computer
4. Install new additional Android Device in Android Device Manager

Comment: This issue is also preventing me from publishing for Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by following steps outlined in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lZldOqg5i0&t=525s

Before making any changes, when I ran `dotnet workload search` in a Terminal window, I got this result which is missing `maui-android`.

[image: Terminal Output before changes]

So I ran `sudo dotnet workload install maui` and `sudo dotnet workload install maui-android` and now I have this list:

[image: Terminal Output after changes]

I restarted Visual Studio and I was able to debug again with the Android Emulator and also publish for Android again.

Comment: Thanks! But you shouldn't need to install separately all SDKs. I had exactly same issue on Android, and only installing MAUI workload with command "sudo dotnet workload install maui" resolved my issue. Indeed, "maui" workload is a ".NET MAUI SDK for all platforms".

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a Xamarin Android App and I solved it by deleting all of my user settings located under `/Users/[USER]/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio`
Not an optimal solution (all keybindings gone etc) but at least i can debug again.

The problem started after enabling the setting `Other/Preview features/Use .NET 8` but didn't go away after disabling this.